# RadiobuttonFor in Mvc Razor syntax

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three radio buttons and my field value type is **integer** like Maintenance for 3, 
Active for 1 and Inactive for 2.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "3") Maintenance
@if (Model.IsReady == true)
{
    <span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId,"1") Active</span>
}
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "2") Inactive
```

i using above code then insert data properly but when my form open in edit mode then i have not got any radio button selected.

and i also used below code but not get success.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "3", Model.StatusId == '3' ? new {Checked = "checked"} : null) Maintenance
@if (Model.IsReady == true)
{
    <span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "1",Model.StatusId == '1' ? new {Checked = "checked"} : null) Active</span>
}
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "2",Model.StatusId == '2' ? new {Checked = "checked"} : null) Inactive
```

so how to get selected radio button in edit mode

thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The way I create radiobuttons is as follows:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId,3,new { id = "rbMaintenance" })
@Html.Label("rbMaintenance","Maintenance")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId,2,new { id = "rbInactive" })
@Html.Label("rbInactive","Inactive")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId,1,new { id = "rbActive" })
@Html.Label("rbActive","Active")
```

The difference to your code really is that as your StatusId type is Int then you should enter the value in the RadioButtonFor as an integer e.g. 3 for Maintenance rather than '3'.